# Gcloud beta emulators data store start error Google/Cloud is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In developing php appengine standard app, I wanted a local development datastore  so I ran- `gcloud  components install cloud-datastore-emulator`
I also installed google cloud data store globally using

> composer require google\cloud_datastore

After that tried to start the emulator with

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore  start --data-dir="C:\Users\Hellen\Desktop\New folder\myDstore"
```

But the command failed with the following output.

> WARNING: Reusing existing data in [C:\Users\Hellen\Desktop\New folder\myDstore].
>   Executing: cmd /c C:\Users\Hellen\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\cloud-datastore-emulator\cloud_datastore_emulator.cmd start --host=localhost --port=8081 --store_on_disk=True --consistency=0.9 --allow_remote_shutdown C:\Users\Hellen\Desktop\New folder\myDstore
>   [datastore] 'C:\Users\Hellen\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [datastore] operable program or batch file.

Can someone tell me what the problem is? I really don't know what next to try.

Comment: It looks like a bug related to parsing the SDK path with spaces in it - note the string interpreted as a command ending at the space in `Cloud SDK`? Can you try installing the SDK in a different location, without spaces in its path. Or renaming that dir and updating the environment accordingly?

Comment: Actually more along the lines of quoting the executable path with spaces in it before passing it to the shell.

Comment: I think the fault most have being mine, when I ran 'gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator' nothing was install, rather than retrace and find out why because I missed the step of requiring datastore library using composer, before running 'gcloud beta emulators datastore start' at this point something was installed, what was it that was install and where was it installed? I cannot tell, i believe thats what's behind the errors am confronting.

Comment: The SDK you want me to reinstall is it the googleAppEngine?

Comment: No, I mean the cloud SDK (note the name and path in the `Executing...` log line you quoted. Looks like the installation location was `C:\Users\Hellen\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK` (with space in it), under which the installation script created the `google-cloud-sdk` dir where the SDK actually exists. If that installation path was your choice and not created by default at reinstall just drop the `/Cloud SDK` from it (it's redundant anyways) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had both app engine server installed and Google cloud SDK, and both have similar commands. So I uninstalled both and installed only gcloud SDK. Thanks so much for the hint.